Uniqueness problem of constant coefficient differential operator with given boundary information on compact domain
I'm considering the uniqueness problem for a constant coefficient differential operator $A$ on compact domain $\Omega$ with given boundary information such that we have
\begin{equation}\label{overdetermined problem of constant coefficient}
        \left\{\begin{aligned}
            Au&=0&\hspace{5pt}&\text{in}&\hspace{5pt}&\Omega\subset\mathbb{R}^n\\
            \partial_\nu^ku&=f_k&\hspace{5pt}&\text{on}&\hspace{5pt}&\partial\Omega
        \end{aligned}\right.
    \end{equation}
Whene can we have uniqueness and existence of solutions? For example, I know when $A=\Delta$ and $k=0$ there exists one unique solution. I'm wondering if we can have some similar results for any constant coefficient differential operator.
By the way, I'm not sure whether I need to substitude 'for' by 'of' in the phrase 'the cauchy problem for a constant coefficient differential operator $A$ on compact domain $\Omega$' or not. Please let me know if I were wrong.

The problem you are asking about is not a Cauchy problem since the condition are specified on the whole boundary of the domain $\partial\Omega$, while for a true Cauchy problem the behaviour at a particular part of the boundary is not required. Typically the conditions $\partial_\nu^k u =f_k$ are stated only for (possibly even a compact subset of) an hypersurface, but not on the whole boundary of the domain of definition.

@DanieleTampieri thank you for pointing that out. I've changed it.
